# How to show radio button in perfect way using bootstrap ?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am using bootstrap . my code for Radio Button is

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Gender</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender">Female</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender">Male</label>

                </div>
```

Comment: you need large radio like showing in your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix for your question

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Gender</label>
<label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio"  name="gender">Female</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender">Male</label></div>
```

just one change remove form-control class from your code it will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Following [Bootstrap V3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) documentation you have the perfect example on how to structure input type radio with label:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
```

As you can see the input and text are both inside 1 single label.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your radio button.Your radio button is properly shown?,the problem is with the look and style. you have added form-control class to radio button so its using the default CSS of form-control.
Either style the radio button by your own CSS or just remove the form-control class and verify the opening-closing of tags